# How to import .mqo files?

Tags: import

I recently downloaded a model that is works in MMD (which is a .PMX file) but when i went to import it, it showed it as an .mqo file. I've looked everywhere but couldn't find an add-on that supports .mqo file. Anyone got one? Thanks!

Comment: I use 3D software since the 90s but I really don't know what MMD or .PMX is. In order to receive good answers you might want to add some more information to your question *by using the edit link below it*.

Comment: Me too, but googled a bit... I guess is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MikuMikuDance? .mqo should be a MetaSequoia file type http://mikumikudance.wikia.com/wiki/Metasequoia. You could try asking to add mqo support here https://github.com/sugiany/blender_mmd_tools, perhaps.